# how to merge or concatenate two list of maps in typescript?

Tags: javascript

I have 2 list of maps like

```
payload1 = [
    {
      'series': 'abc',
      'value' : 123,
      'date'  : '2020-06-22'
    }, { 
      'series': 'efg',
      'value' : 789,
      'date'  : '2020-06-21'
    } ]
```

and

```
    payload2 = [
    {
      'series': 'xyz',
      'value' : 234,
      'date'  : '2020-06-22'
    }, { 
      'series': 'tuv',
      'value' : 23442,
      'date'  : '2020-06-21'
    } ]
```

How can I genrate a new list of map like

```
  payload = [
    {
      'series': 'abc',
      'value' : 123,
      'date'  : '2020-06-22'
    }, { 
      'series': 'efg',
      'value' : 789,
      'date'  : '2020-06-21'
    }, {
      'series': 'xyz',
      'value' : 234,
      'date'  : '2020-06-22'
    }, { 
      'series': 'tuv',
      'value' : 23442,
      'date'  : '2020-06-21'
    } ]
```

Basically i need to concatenate 2 list of maps to create a new one. is there any way to do this with less iteration??

Comment: `const payload = [...payload1, ...payload2]`?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the spread operator "..." to merge the elements of two objects or arrays into one.

```
let payload = [...payload1, ...payload2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `Array.concat()` function.

```js
let payload1 = [
    {
      'series': 'abc',
      'value' : 123,
      'date'  : '2020-06-22'
    }, { 
      'series': 'efg',
      'value' : 789,
      'date'  : '2020-06-21'
    } ];

    let payload2 = [
    {
      'series': 'xyz',
      'value' : 234,
      'date'  : '2020-06-22'
    }, { 
      'series': 'tuv',
      'value' : 23442,
      'date'  : '2020-06-21'
    } ];

let payload = payload1.concat(payload2);
console.log(payload);
```